# How make first div wider than second in one line

Tags: html, css

I made 3 forms in 3 separately DIV and I need to make first div wider than second and third.How I can achieve this? It`s possible to do that with "float" ?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.item-1 { 
    float: left; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 240px;;
    border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 div.item-2 { 
    float: left; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 div.item-3 { 
    float: left; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #000;

 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="item-1">.1.</div>
<div class="item-2">.2.</div>
<div class="item-3">.3.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to do this:

[image]

Comment: You can't do that. HTML elements are **rectangular**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider pseudo element with the first element:

```css
div.item-1 {
  float: left;
  margin:5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom:none;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
}
div.item-1:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top:none;
  background:linear-gradient(#000,#000) top right/200px 1px no-repeat,red;
  top:100%;
  height:50px;
  left:-1px;
  right:-201px;
}

div.item-2 {
  float: left;
  margin:5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background:red;
}

div.item-3 {
  float: left;
  margin:5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-1">.1.</div>
<div class="item-2">.2.</div>
<div class="item-3">.3.</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I need ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, only visually fake it :

```css
div {
  padding:1em;
  float:right;
  background:brown;
  border:solid;
  margin:0 10px 30px;
  width:30%;
  min-height:40vh;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 21px white,0 23px,-23px 0 , -23px 23px 0 ;
}
.item-2 {
  margin-left:40px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 21px white,0 23px,-23px 0 , -23px 23px 0, 20px 23px ;
}
.item-3 {
  float:none;
  width:auto;
  min-height:70vh;
  box-shadow:0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-1">.1.</div>
<div class="item-2">.2.</div>
<div class="item-3">.3.</div>
```

**Note**

- float reverse them
- box-shadow is used to hide and fake the shape and the borders
- as soon as item-1 and item-2 have different heights, the visual breaks.

I do not advise to use this.

Answer (score -1):

For you to do that, you must do somewaht of an "hacky" solution. Something along these lines, using css grid:

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
 display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
}

div.item-1 {  
    width: 150px;
    height: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 0;
    grid-row: 1/3;
 }
 div.item-2 { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 0;
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 2;
 }
 div.item-3 { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #000;

 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">.1.</div>
  <div class="item-2"></div>
 <div class="item-3">.2.</div>
 <div class="item-3">.3.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see 2 divs, not only one

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but in that case I can't make space between them, but thanks anyway for the answer